# PHP/Ubuntu: Intense background tasks - sepreate server, or bigger single server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I manage a Ubuntu 16 server (running a public website), on AWS EC2 infrastructure.

The site has a number of fairly intense, and regular background tasks (via cron) to do, and it's running the risk of overloading current resources and therefore affecting end users / public.

The database is hosted on AWS RDS.

I'm unsure whether to:

1. Simply increase the resources available on the single EC2 (it's currently a t2.small, so really very little resources)
2. Launch a separate server, solely for the background tasks, so any lag a background task may cause on the server won't affect end-users (the database is on RDS so would be a pretty easy setup)

I thought about setting up AWS Load Balancing and Auto Scaling but came across two issues:

1. Scaling can take 60 seconds plus, so the end-users will still experience potential lag
2. All servers in the autoscaling group will be the same, therefore all running their own instances of the regular background tasks, resulting in potential double-ups, and more importantly, each server won't be better off as each is still doing what a single is asked of.

I am leaning towards a separate server for the tasks, as it means if that falls over (or lags), end-users aren't affected at all, and it seems a 'tidy' option, but is a bit more admin and setup. Cost of having a second server isn't an issue.

So my question is really, what do you think is best, and why? And am I missing a better idea?

(NB improving the efficiency of the background tasks isn't an option!)

Thanks in advance
Rob

Comment: Are the tasks CPU, disk, or database intensive? Or intensive on multiple / other resources?

Comment: CPU, RAM and MySQL intensive. MySQL use would be significant during many of the tasks. Not disk. Hmmz so maybe I need to look at RDS resources as well...

Comment: You could have an RDS read replica if it's not writing to the database. If it's using CPU and RAM you can either upsize your instance or have a script that creates a spot instance, runs the batch task, then turns the instance off, which could save costs. You could consider running it in lambda as well, if it would work there.

Comment: @Tim, it needs RDS write access, and a post instance, whilst a good idea, isn't practical, as the background tasks are constant - repeat each and every minute. It won't work on lambda either, unfortunately (well, it might but with a huge amount of config (time and cost). I'm tempted by splitting it, and a dedicated "tasks" server, as it seems like a tidy approach, much like splitting the MySQL server off to it's own too and then I always know, whatever is going on with the task server, the web server won't be effected.

Comment: Suggest you need to add more detailed information to your question, having to keep asking questions to understand the problem reduces the number of people who will help you. If it's an "every minute" batch job my first advice is that's not a batch job and you need to re-architect whatever it is you're doing. Batch jobs tend to be daily or perhaps at most hourly, otherwise to my mind they're not batch jobs. What you have is a slightly delayed interactive task. You might as well just increase the size of your primary instance.